# How to set up Terraform "COMMAND: REMOTE CONFIG" with consul

Tags: file-sharing, consul, terraform

I have a server I am using for self healing and auto scaling of a consul cluster.  It does this by with terraform scripts that are run by consul watches and health checks.

I want to add an additional backup terraform server for failover.  To do this I must share the `terraform.tfstate` and `terraform.tfstate.backup` between my servers so that they can run terraform on the same resources.  I would like to share these files using the [Terraform "COMMAND: REMOTE CONFIG"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/remote-config.html), but to me it is unclear as to how I would begin the share.

Basically I want the `terraform.tfstate` and `terraform.tfstate.backup` files to constantly be in sync on both servers.  Here is my attempt at setting this up. Note that both terraform servers are running consul clients connected to the rest of my consul cluster:

```
terraform remote config \
-backend=consul \
-backend-config="address=localhost:8500" \
-backend-config="path=/consul-scripts/terr/terraform.tfstate" \
-backend-config="backup=/consul-scripts/terr/terraform.tfstate.backup" \
-path="/consul-scripts/terr/terraform.tfstate" \
-backup="/consul-scripts/terr/terraform.tfstate.backup" \
-address="localhost:8500"
```

However this was obviously the wrong syntax.  When trying to run the consul example provided on the linked documentation I received the following output:

```
username@hostname:/consul-scripts/terr$ terraform remote config \
>     -backend=consul \
>     -backend-config="address=localhost:8500" \
>     -backend-config="path=/consul-scripts/terr/terraform.tfstate"
Error writing backup state file: open terraform.tfstate.backup: permission denied
```

I would like to have my terraform servers sync up through the Terraform "COMMAND: REMOTE CONFIG" instead of a normal file share system like glusterfs or something.

How can I correctly sync my terraform files in this way?

Comment: That error message suggests that you got the remote config command correct enough that Terraform tried to enable remote state, but whatever user you're running `terraform` as does not have write access to create or update the `terraform.tfstate.backup` file in the local filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yea [@Martin Atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins) got it right I just had to run the example in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/remote-config.html) with sudo. Using the `terraform remote config` will store the .tfstate files in a hidden directory `.terraform/` within the directory containing the terraform scripts.

How `terraform remote config` works is that it creates a key value in consul that contains the details of the tfstate file.

The answer is very close to what is listed in the documentation.  In practice using `terraform remote config` is a 3 step process.

Before running terraform the following should be run to pull the current tfstate file:

```
#this will pull the current tfstate file
#if none exists it will create the tfstate key value
terraform remote config \
-backend=consul \
-backend-config="address=localhost:8500" \
-backend-config="path=tfstate" \
pull
```

Then run:

```
terraform apply
```

After this is finished run the following to push the updated tfstate file out to consul in order to change the key value:

```
terraform remote config \
-backend=consul \
-backend-config="address=localhost:8500" \
-backend-config="path=tfstate" \
push
```